# Static data query - self service Amadeus API in production environment

Tags: amadeus, static-data

I am currently developing a web app using self-service Amadeus API in a production environment, I have questions related to the static data, kindly reply.

Questions:

```
1. Is there any static data available related to flights schedule or any other detail which we can store on our end and get it synced in some scheduled manner, in place of fetching all data every time using APIs.

2. In case we have static data then what will be the ideal time duration to refresh data.

3. Are we allowed to store real-time data on our end temporarily? If yes then for what duration we can keep a copy of same.

4. Is there any API where we will send a list of Flight/Segment Id and get details only of those selected records. What I mean is we like to know details of 10 specific flights/segments. So can we get the information related to those 10 flights/segments whose id we will pass to API?

5. What's the response time of search API and API which returns details of the flight.

6. What all filters available in search API to filter data.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. As of today, ee do not provide static data for flights schedule
2. /
3. You are allowed to store the data coming from the flight search API as long as you do not resell it in any way. Keep in mind that this data changes a lot (price/availability)
4. You can use the [Flight Offers Price API](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-price) for this. Flight Offers Price takes a list of flight-offers (that you get by using the [Flight Offers Search](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search) API). For those flights-offers the API revalidates the price and the availability.
5. It depends on where you are based, which API you use and how you use it (filters), you can try our APIs for free in our test environment. Keep in mind that the test environment is limited in terms of the number of API calls, data and has a slower response time than the production environment
6. Our catalog is fully open (no need to register) you can find the Flight Offers Search reference documentation [here](https://developers.amadeus.com/self-service/category/air/api-doc/flight-offers-search/api-reference) listing all the parameters available. The Flight Offers Search API has 2 endpoints:

   - `GET` a simpler version of the search, easy and fast to implement but offering less filtering
   - `POST` offering a full access to all the functionalities of the flight search